# Calculate average from sources that sends data at different time.

Tags: java

In my current project, I am going to write a function of calculating average Temperature.

A notatable  point of this function is that  it receives data from many temperature sources at different time. Could you advise me "How can I write a function with such a behavior?"

For instance,  following function receives `tempSensorData` from many **temperature Sensors, which sends temperature data at different time**. I need to write a logic of calculating average temperature.

```
public void calculateRoomAvgTemp(TempStruct tempSensorData) {

   // Write logic of calculating Average Temperature.

}
```

Comment: 1) Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such. 2) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you. (And please don't claim that code snippet is an attempt - it reads more like a specification.)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? What is in TempStruct, and where are the temperatures being stored (cache vs db?)

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) is what you need

Comment: @John kane : TempStruct is a structure with two fields. Temperature Value as double and UnitOfMeasurement as String.

Comment: As a side note, maybe make UnitOfMeasurement an Enum it may be a little cleaner.

Comment: Many Many thanks John Kane. I will follow your advise and do same. :)

Comment: Where are you holding the temperature values? Are they all kept in memory, or in a db? Does the method to calculate the average need to take in a value? Or could it just know where to look for the appropriate set of values?

Comment: Dear john Kane, I do not store temperature value in the database. I keep it in memory.

Comment: Last question (hopefully), do you need to calculate the average temperature for a given source or all at once, and do you calculate the total average or would this be be weighted/smoothed etc?

Comment: I will get temperature value from different  temperature sensors at different time and then, I will calculate average of all values.

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question what you mean by "at different times". Does one sensor send you data every five minutes and another only once per hour and you need to average those two because they represent the same location?

Comment: There are many sensors, who sends data at different time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just keep a running average? Assuming that your method gets called each time a temperature reading is taken, you can do the following:

```
private final List<Double> temps = Collections
        .synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Double>());
private double currentAverage = 0d;

public void calculateRoomAvgTemp(TempStruct tempSensorData) {
    synchronized (this.temps) {
        this.temps.add(tempSensorData.temp);
        this.currentAverage = 0d;

        for (Double temp : this.temps) {
            this.currentAverage += temp;       
        }

        this.currentAverage /= this.temps.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Epoch. this answer is also quite relevant and useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

can you store past temperatures in a separate field in the class? I noticed that your method is void, therefore doesn't return anything. I'm going to assume you want to store the average in the separate field. Example:

```
public class TempCalculator {
    private double totalTemp = 0;
    private int sensors = 0;
    private double averageTemp = 0;

    public void calculateRoomAvgTemp(TempStruct tempSensorData) {
        totalTemp += tempSensorData.getTemp(); // Assuming getTemp() exists
        sensors += 1;
        averageTemp = totalTemp / sensors;
    }

    public double getAvgTemp() {
        return averageTemp;
    }
}
```

Of course, this can be done with a list if you want to store temperatures used and shaped to your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many Many thanks for your efforts and time. It is quite relevant and useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

one way I could think of - insert values as you receive them into an ArrayList.  If you need to calculate the average temperature after each data point that you receive, run through a for loop and average out the data points in the ArrayList to get the required value.  One could look into using memoization to avoid running through the loop for all values.

Another option would be to use apache commons math whereby you can use the descriptive statistics option (using a rolling array) to get the mean (average).

I am assuming your code is single threaded.  If multithreaded, you could use a thread safe vector (or add locks/synchronization on your own).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the average without keeping all historic values in memory (or a database), use a "[moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)". This mathematical tool can give you the new average from the last one plus the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one thread which will calculate the temperature and many which will measure it values from different places. When some measurement is done the thread pushes the result into e.g. `LinkedBlockingQueue`. It's important to synchronize this operation because many threads might try to push results at the same time. The thread which calculate average temperature would run in a loop, pop new result from the queue, recalculate the temperature and then once again try to pop another result. As far as the queue will be empty the thread would be blocked on reading from it. In this way you would have an asynchronous communication between threads and the average temperature would be recalculated immediately after the measurements are done.